# Cake PHP 2 order model query results by array order

Tags: php, sql, arrays, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I'm doing some dev work in a Cake PHP 2 project. I have a model called `QueueManagerJob` and a column called `queue`, I need to be able to order the data retrieved on this model by the order of an array *(converted by a comma separated list)*, I initially thought that Cake would be able to handle this when given an array, but it doesn't seem to be?

I have a variable holding an array called `$queue` which looks like:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "now"
  [1]=>
  string(5) "later"
  [2]=>
  string(7) "default"
}
```

My model query is:

```php
$jobs = $this->QueueManagerJob->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'QueueManagerJob.reserved_at' => null,
        'QueueManagerJob.queue' => $queue
    ),
    'order' => array(
        'QueueManagerJob.available_at' => 'desc'
    ),
    'limit' => $limit
));
```

I could, in theory perform three queries, I could loop over my `$queue` array since a foreach would be in order, and perform a query in each one and then merge at a later date but this would be quite inefficient I think as there's going to be an unknown number of queues.

Comment: Do you want to use an array to sort (`order`) or to query (`conditions`)? Code seems to contradict everything else.

Comment: Ideally a single `condition` ordered by the items in the array.